# Decimal/float/int - деление больших чисел

Tags: python, деление, длинная-арифметика

Нужна помощь в решении проблемы больших чисел в Python, а именно деление больших степеней и факториалов. Т.е. при попытке делить условные

```
(4 ** 512) / (5.5 ** 300)
```

я получаю

> ```
> int too large to convert to float
> ```

Я пробовал применять decimal, но проблема осталась:

> ```
> decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
> ```

Похожие проблемы при попытке деления больших факториалов:

> ```
> integer division result too large for a float
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal):

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal(4 ** 512) / Decimal(5.5 ** 300))
# 1.399293161342312549090562061E+86
```

Comment: Кажется понял в чем была ошибка - то есть decimal нужно перед каждым числом в выражении ставить?

Comment: или так: `print("{:>,.7f}".format(Decimal(4 ** 512) / Decimal(5.5 ** 300)))` :)

Comment: А есть способ по умолчанию для всех чисел или переменных decimal использовать?

Comment: @hitandfun, нет это ведь отдельный объект с своим типом Decimal, а обычные целые и вещественные числа это объекта с типом int и float